# How do i add another filter to my VBA Code?

Tags: excel, vba, filtering, autofilter

I've created code in VBA that filters my data befre transferring but I'd like to add an additional filter.

How would I go about that ?

I've tried simply adding a row under Criteria 1 with the new values but it doesn't work.

```
 With Wb1.Sheets(12)
            If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
            .Range("$A$1:$AM" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter Field:=19, _
     Criteria1:="Test,Test"
            Set rngToCopy = .AutoFilter.Range
        End With
        rngToCopy.Copy
        wb2.Sheets(2).Range("$A1").PasteSpecial xlValues
    End If
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

Still having issues for some reason, here's the entire code. When I execute, I dont' receive an error, but nothing copies.

```
Sub CopyData()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandle


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    Dim Wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wB As Workbook
    Dim rngToCopy As Range


    For Each wB In Application.Workbooks
        If Left(wB.Name, 21) = "Test_Test Test" Then
            Set Wb1 = wB
            Exit For
        End If
    Next


    If Not Wb1 Is Nothing Then '<~~ check if you actually found the needed workbook
        Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
 With Wb1.Sheets(12).Range("$A$1:$AM" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        If AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        .AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="Test,Test"
        .AutoFilter Field:=38, Criteria1:="Employee"
        'do stuff
        Set rngToCopy = .AutoFilter.Range
   End With
   rngToCopy.Copy
        wb2.Sheets(2).Range("$A1").PasteSpecial xlValues
    End If
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

Comment: What is the other filter criteria? On what field? (I.E. are you filtering the same column?)

Comment: Slightly different parameters but same concept.

It would be Field: =38 and Criteria2:="Employee".  

I'm just not sure of the syntax.

Comment: I updated the answer; when I combined your with statement to include the range, I failed to remove the `.` from `.Cells(.Rows`, a hazard of copy_paste

Comment: I appreciate your help, but still something's not quite meshing right.  I don't receive an error, but nothing happens when I run my macro. i've updated the question to include my entire code. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter a range for multiple criteria in a single column use `Or`...

```
With Wb1.Sheets(12).Range("$A$1:$AM" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    .AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="Test,Test", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="No"
    'Do stuff
End With
```

To filter more than 2 criteria in a column you must use an array...

```
Criteria1:=Array("Test,Test", "No", "Yes")
```

To filter a range for multiple criteria in different columns (you must set two fields)...

```
    With Wb1.Sheets(12).Range("$A$1:$AM" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        If AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        .AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="Test,Test"
        .AutoFilter Field:=38, Criteria1:="Employee"
        'do stuff
   End With
```

Comment: For some reason I get "Invalid or unqualified reference" when i try this method.

Comment: This has been marked as "accepted". Did you resolve the issue mentioned in the above comment? If so then please indicate how you've resolved it, or remove the comment.